# C# Why i get a NotSupported Exception on my file Path

Tags: c#, streamreader

```
StreamReader fr = new StreamReader("D:\\test\\" + item);
```

This is what i want to do.  Item is a String with the filename. The hole string is like that

```
"D:\\test\\01-Marriotts Island.mp3"
```

befor he tries to generate the StreamReader.
whats wrong with the path?

Comment: Markus, did you manage to solve your problem? If so, what turned out to be the cause of the exception? The reason I ask is that I just want to make sure my answer is indeed accurate and does not mislead anyone who comes across it in the future eg if it turns out to be that the path itself was not well-formed.

Comment: i use now the method File.ReadBinary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StreamReader is designed for reading character data. You should use [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) instead if you are trying to read a binary data, such as the contents of an mp3 file.

Update: As Marc pointed out you could also use a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) to read the file and this may provide an easier to use interface for manipulating the file than BinaryReader. Also, I second his recommendation to use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) when building up the path to the file you want to access.

Comment: Good spot. I'm not sure I'd use `BinaryReader` though - just a `Stream`

Answer (score 4):

Is there any more message that goes with it? For info, the easiest way to combine paths is with `Path.Combine`:

```
using(StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(@"D:\Test", item))) {
   // ...
}
```

(note also the `using` to ensure it is disposed)

or clearer still (IMO):

```
using(StreamReader fr = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(@"D:\Test", item))) {
    // ...
}
```

(of course, as has been mentioned elsewhere, a `StreamReader` may be inappropriate for mp3)

Answer (score 2):

Consulting the [MSDN documentation for StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx), I don't see `NotSupportedException` listed as an exception that this API will throw.  However, [another similar constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5.aspx) does list it:

> `NotSupportedException`: path includes
>   an incorrect or invalid syntax for
>   file name, directory name, or volume
>   label.

So I tried it myself with an invalid volume label and indeed got `NotSupportedException`:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("DD:\\file.txt");

// throws...
//
// Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
```

So my guess is there is something wrong with your path.